# How to referesh select list (based on SQL query) without refreshing the entire page? APEX 19.1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a select list based on an SQL query.

On that same page, I have a Modal dialog Interactive Grid that allows me to insert a new record on the table that that select list SQL query is referring to.

After I insert a row, then I have to reload the entire page for that option to appear on the select list.

How can I solve this problem? This is, how can I avoid having to reload the entire page?

[image: image of form]

Notice that `cliente` and `name` are referring to the same column on the same table.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this by means of a dynamic action on the page where is the list to be refreshed.

A :Create a dynamic action :

1. Event : Dialog Closed
2. Selection Type : Region or Item
3. List item Region/Item(s) :  The Region or Item(s) from where to modal page was opened.

B : Associate a Refresh action

1. Selection : Type Region or Item(s)
2. Region / Item(s) : The Region or Item(s) to be refreshed.